# Как сделать, чтобы JS "увидел" сгенерированный элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть кнопка:

```
<button id="btn1">BTN</button>
```

При нажатии на неё, создаётся другая:

```
$('#btn1').on("click", function() {
  $('body').append("<button id='btn2'>BTN2</button>");
});
```

И вот уже её "он клик" не будет работать:

```
$('#btn2').on("click", function() {
  alert("WORK!");
});
```

Как сделать, чтобы JS заметил этот блок?

Comment: `$(document).on("click", '#btn2', function() {`

Comment: Большое спасибо!